# Пишу игру на пайтон с модулём pygame, создал механику прыжка, но он работает только один раз повторно прыжок сделать не получается

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption('Cubes Game')

x = 50
y = 425
widht = 40
height = 60
speed = 5
isjump = False
jumpCount = 10

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5 :
        x -=speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - widht - 5 :
        x += speed
    if not(isjump):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
           isjump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            if jumpCount < 0:
                y += (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isjump = True
            xjumpCount = 10

    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,225), (x, y, widht, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Судя по коду у вас должно быть наоборот - прыжок должен бесконечно повторяться, ведь вы нигде не сбрасываете флаг `isjump` в `False`.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности: не надо в заголовок запихивать весь текст вопроса.

Comment: ошибка не выскакивает?

Answer (score 1):

у тебя `xjumpCount = 10` вместо `jumpCount = 10` написано.